# How to read sql table on Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, sqlconnection

I am trying to create a basic flow on Nifi

> 1. read table from sql
> 2. process it on python
> 3. write back another table in sql

It is simple as it is.

[image: Nifi flow]

But, I am facing issues when I try to read data on python

As far as I learn I need to use sys.stdin/out.
It only reads and writes as below.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
file.to_csv(sys.stdout,index=False)
```

Below you can find processor properties, but I don't think it is the issue.

QueryDatabaseTableRecord:

[image: QueryDatabaseTableRecord]

ExecuteStreamCommand:
[image]

PutDatabaseRecord:
[image]

Error Message:

[image]

Comment: query table returns data in `avro` format, and you are trying to read `csv` in python

Comment: just change the `record writer` parameter in `query table` processor to CSVRecordSetWriter.

Comment: you're absolutely right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier way to do this if you're running 1.12.0 or newer: `ScriptedTransformRecord`. It's like `ExecuteScript` except it works on a per-record basis. This is what a simple Groovy script for it looks like:

```
def fullName = record.getValue("FullName")
def nameParts = fullName.split(/[\s]{1,}/)
record.setValue("FirstName", nameParts[0])
record.setValue("LastName:", nameParts[1])
record
```

It's a new processor, so there's not **that much** documentation on it yet aside from the (very good) documentation bundled with it. So samples might be sparse at the moment. If you want to use and run into issues, feel free to join the nifi-users mailing list and asked for more detailed help.

Comment: Thanks for the information, where can I subscribe the mailing list?